# How to use scala types Either or Option properly

Tags: scala

I am a newbie in scala. And what I understand is, scala discourage to use try, catch, finally block. Rather it promotes the `Option`, `Try` and Either` types.

I want to understand how to use them properly in following case.

**Function to Read property file**

```
  def getSourcePath(properties: Properties): Path = {
    val dataFileURI: String = properties.getProperty("dataFileURI")
    val srcPath = new Path(dataFileURI)
    srcPath
  }
```

**Function That uses value from getSourcePath**

```scala
  val srcPath = getSourcePath(properties)
  def getDataFileName(srcPath: Path, auditID: String): String = {
    val dataFileName: String = srcPath.getName + "_" + auditID
    dataFileName
  }
```

**GetSourcePath that returns Either**

```scala
  def getSourcePath(properties: Properties): Either[FileSystemError, Path] = {
    try{
      val dataFileURI: String = properties.getProperty("dataFileURI")
      val srcPath = new Path(dataFileURI)
      Right(srcPath)  
    }catch{
      case exception: Exception => Left(FileSystemError("Not able to get dataFileURI"))
    }
```

**getDataFileName to use Either.**

```scala
def getDataFileName(srcPath: Either[FileSystemError, Path], auditID: String): Either[FileSystemError, String] = {
    srcPath match {
      case Right(srcPath) => Right(srcPath.getName + "_" + auditID)
      case Left(srcPath) => Left(srcPath)
    }
  }
```

However, This is just like passing exception further in methods. And doing pattern match for each argument looks an overkill, If I have 3-4 arguments.

Seems like I have not fully understand this types.

Comment: What exactly you want to know i mean, Monads are better way to handle errors that's up to you which monad you are going to use depends on your use case. If there is chance that you can get data or null from may be some db call or API you can go with Option Some or None if you want to catch the exception or value, and pass it you can use Either

Comment: @RamanMishra not about which monads to use. It's about how to use it effectively.  In this particular case, if I have 5 arguments which takes `Either` I will have to write pattern matching for all of them. Which looks overkill to me.  may be becuase I am not using it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would write the code. I would use a Try monad, because it is the most concise. Either works too, but you have to use an explicit error type, and that makes things more verbose. So I would stick with Try.

```
def getSourcePath(properties: Properties): Try[Path] = 
  Try(new Path(properties.getProperty("dataFileURI")))

def getDataFileName(srcPath: Try[Path], auditID: String): Try[String] = 
  srcPath.map(_.getName + "_" + auditID)
```

If you want to convert to Option, call toOption on the Try monad that is returned from either of the functions.

If you have questions about how the code works, I can answer in the comments section

Comment: nice to see I can use map on Try so that I don't have to use pattern matching